# Mac OS dictionary app shows some Hangul characters as blanks

Tags: macos, fonts, utf-8, dictionary

[image: Korean font missing]

This screenshot shows what happens when I look up the Korean dictionary inside my Mac OS's default Dictionary app. Apparently some characters are missing and are substituted by empty squares. Moreover, the Hangul symbols inside the red circles should form a single character which they don't. It seems that the problem only happens when the character involves Hangul symbols that are obsolete (not in use anymore in the modern language).

What exactly is the problem and what can I do to improve on this situation?

I am on Mac OS Mojave 10.14.1.

Comment: Shouldn't this be rather asked on askdifferent SE (https://apple.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @Ale My bad. Thanks for the advice. Do you think it would be appropriate for me to delete this post?

Comment: I don't think you are *required* to delete your post (but you might ask more about this on meta.superuser.com), however given that it has no votes and no answers, I wouldn't feel like it is inappropriate to delete it, especially if in the meantime you posted it on AskDifferent.